# Check NSString for special characters

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, special-characters

I want to check an NSString for special characters, i.e. anything except a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

I don't need to check how many special characters are present, or their positions, I just need to know whether a particular string contains any or not. If it does, then I want to be able to display "Error!", or something similar.

For example,  **jHfd9982** is OK but **asdJh992@** is not.

Also, letters with accents, diacritics, etc. should not be allowed.

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

if ([aString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
}
```

You could also use a regex (this syntax is from RegexKitLite: http://regexkit.sourceforge.net ):

```
if ([aString isMatchedByRegex:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"]) {
  NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't affect the logic, but FYI, there are two 'K's in the character set.

Comment: @Dave DeLong In your case, you can not deal with such unicodes like ""m³","m²","ft²","ft³","°C","°F","°K", etc"

Comment: use this
NSCharacterSet *s = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_"] invertedSet];

Comment: damn i down voted this instead of up voting this and now i can't change it.  This good solution!

Comment: Why not use `[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]` ?

Comment: @rustyMagnet because `+alphanumericCharacterSet` came out 5 years ago, but this answer is from 10 years ago... ;) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Dave DeLong.  Time flies when coding.

Answer (score 10):

Here the code you can use it to check the string has any special character or not

```
NSString *string = <your string>;

NSString *specialCharacterString = @"!~`@#$%^&*-+();:={}[],.<>?\\/\"\'";
NSCharacterSet *specialCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet
                                       characterSetWithCharactersInString:specialCharacterString];

if ([string.lowercaseString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:specialCharacterSet].length) {                
    NSLog(@"contains special characters");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to search NSString using a character set if it cant find any characters in the string then rangeOfCharacterFromSet: will return a range of {NSNotFound, 0}

The character set would be like [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] or your own set. Note you can also invert character sets so you could have a set of acceptable characters

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove special characters & numbers from any string (even textfield text), while you are editing, these lines below are quite handy:

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"!~`@#$%^&*-+();:=_{}[],.<>?\\/|\"\'0123456789"

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return (![string isEqualToString:filtered]) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Instead of "return (![string isEqualToString:filtered]) ? NO : YES;", why not just "return [string isEqualToString:filtered];"?

Answer (score 2):

This code allows only numbers in UITextField input.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;

}
```

Comment: But the question clearly asked about letters as well.