# ios validating text field input for some characters

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield

I am really new to ios development. while validating a text field i must ensure that it contains only 0-9 and special characters like * and #. Please help me out.

```
- (BOOL)validate:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *exp = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:exp options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything, any code?

Comment: You can set the keyboard type so it will contain only numbers and special characters. look here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: but in ipad, the user has an option to change keyboard. it has an option of ABC in numeric keyboard.

Comment: This might helps you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297102/check-nsstring-for-special-characters

Comment: @user2932169 Add code in body instead of comment. It should be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789*#"] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

NSCharacterSet *numberAndSpecialCharsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789*#"];

return ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:numberAndSpecialCharsSet].location==NSNotFound);
```

}